# Routing public IPs (each a /32) through a VPN to another server

Tags: vpn, routing

Hopefully the title makes sense; I have a server currently in a colo facility, with many IP addresses routed to it. They are individual IPs and not in a contiguous block.

Due to vastly improved connectivity (fibre) at home I am slowly bringing my infrastructure in-house for managability and eventually, cost savings. What I would like to do though is use the IP addresses allocated to my existing server, at home. I have an IP block allocated to me on my new ISP connection, but for a couple of reasons I'd like to make use of the colo ones for now:

1. Ease of transition - lots of domains, dns, hard-coded IPs in programs, etc.
2. Connectivity fallback. If my primary line goes down and switches to
   fallback 1 (dsl) or fallback 2 (4G), I lose access to the
   ISP-allocated IP block of IPs that are only presented on the primary
   WAN interface.

What I'd like to achieve is my home virtualisation server (Proxmox/Debian-based) "dials in" to the colo server in the colo facility (also Proxmox/Debian) via VPN or similar, and gets to make use of the IP addresses that currently terminate on the colo box. If the primary connection to my ISP goes down and one of the fallback routes kicks in, the VPN tunnel will just time out and then be re-established on the backup connection instead.

I'm sure this is doable, but I have no idea how. I'm not afraid to get my hands dirty, I just don't really know where to start?

Comment: Don't host anything important at home.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a broad question so it's hard to give very specific answers, but the way I'd solve it by building a VPN between your home network and your server using either OpenVPN or some IPsec based solution like OpenSwan (might be a bit tougher to configure). On your router set the default gateway to the VPN connection (OpenVPN can push a route for this, probably even better), and on your server, configure NAT so traffic coming from your home network is using one of your server's IP addresses for external connectivity.

Comment: Apologies for the broad start, but when you don't really have a clue of how to achieve something broad is a good place to start. I think "install OpenVPN and play" is probably about as specific as I'm going to get as an answer for now. I was just hoping someone else may have done this or similar already and could throw some tips/iptables rules my way :)